# SUPEE6788 Patch installation magento, Showing error Could not open input file: fixSUPEE6788.php

Tags: magento-1.9, php, patches, supee-6788

I have installed SUPEE6788 Patch, it affected many modules and files and to fix this I have followed https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

But now I am running command `php -f fixSUPEE6788.php -- fixWhitelists`

In terminal it is showing me this error:

> Could not open input file: fixSUPEE6788.php

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a permission problem, try to run:

```
chmod 777 fixSUPEE6788.php
php -f fixSUPEE6788.php --fixWhitelists
```

Comment: @Khushbu_systematix feel free to mark your question as answered so it'll benefit for others